Is there a way to show the arrows for the autonumericInput widget in Shinywidgets? Like the standard numericInput function has?
How to show or enable the step arrows for an autonumericInput from the ShinyWidgets package?
The only option I see is the wheelSteps but it doesn't show the arrows. Perhaps I need to add custom CCS?
AutonumericInput widget:

Normal numericInput widget:


CSS alone will not help since you need interaction to change the value. The autonumeric Javascript library apparently does not include the option to show arrows

Wow, seems like a weird thing not to include. You can't scroll on a tablet...
